# The Stormtroopers know who to take orders from. Are there ways that Star Wars movie fans can tell the difference in their rank?

Tags: star-wars, military-sf

The Imperial Stormtroopers must know who their leaders are so they know their place in the hierarchy. How is it displayed? Is it possible for movie fans to tell the ranks of the armored Stormtroopers, their NCO's or their officers apart?

[image: Stormtroopers]

*Who's the boss*?

Comment: Much more intriguing is that there is apparently only one size of uniform. Compare the second guy from left first row and second row. The guy in front seems smaller than the rest, but is apparently wearing the exact same uniform. If you look closely and compare it to the guy behind him, the uniform seems either too large for the first guy or too small for the second.

Comment: @bitmask It's always like that in boot camp. They have all the sizes, but they won't issue the one you wear.

Comment: Now that you mention it: If your troops are clones, you *would* only manufacture one size, right?

Comment: Most likely a case of "left for too long in the first tube" I'd assume. Just squished head or legs rather than a squished nose (we don't see it). :P

Comment: As I recall the Stormtroopers were originally only composed of clones, but other humans were added along the way (except in the 501st). SWBF2 has you actually fighting clones, in the Kamino Uprising, which supposedly lead the Emperor to discontinue using clones.

Comment: By the time of EP IV, I believe only about 1/3 of the stormtrooper force was clones, and the numbers continued to drop.
@MajorStackings - did my answer suffice? If so, please accept

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Officers could be distinguished in one of two ways. 'Standard' stormtrooper officers:

> Stormtrooper officers were traditionally non-clone graduates from the Imperial Academy, but Imperial stormtroopers who demonstrated skills in leadership could be promoted to officer status. In battle, commissioned stormtrooper officers wore standard armor with rank insignia to indicate status.

There also existed stormtrooper commanders:

> The stormtrooper commanders were separate from the regular officers in the Stormtrooper Corps. Highly skilled in combat and leadership, the commanders were modeled after the ARC troopers, elite clone troopers that fought for the Galactic Republic during the Clone Wars. As a result, they were widely regarded as superior soldiers to the more common Imperial stormtroopers. Because of their special status, the commanders were entrusted with command over the Empire's shadow troopers and were given authority to utilize them at their own discretion without requiring any clearance from Imperial High Command. As an anomaly within an organization that stressed absolute uniformity, the stormtrooper commanders were easily noticeable due to the blue markings on their armor

NCOs could also be identified in armor:

> Non-commissioned officers were identified in the field with shoulder pauldrons instead of the standard rank squares worn over the armor.

All sources are from [here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Stormtrooper#Organization). The only problem is, as far as I've seen, we never see any stormtroopers with these distinguishing marks. Since stormtroopers took orders from Imperial officers, it could be we never saw actual stormtrooper officers or NCOs in the films.

Comment: I'm fairly certain we've at least seen a few NCOs... I could have sworn I remembered those shoulder pauldrons on a book cover or something. Then again, I could just be confusing Clone Wars/transition to Imperial Stormtrooper books for original trilogy ones.

Comment: I know you can see the different ones in the prequel trilogy, but I don't remember any from the original trilogy.

Comment: From the original trilogy, I'm pretty certain we see one of the NCOs with a shoulder pauldron in the "these aren't the droids you're looking for" scene.

Comment: @dangerzone - that might be true, but if so, was that in the original or added in later?

Comment: @SSumner - Unfortunately I cannot answer that. I have the remastered versions (Ghost Hayden and all...). If I had to take a blind guess, I'd say it was in the original. But... blind guess...